# Is it OK to have fatalError in required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) when I don't use Storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, initialization

I have a `ViewController`, which need to be initialized with `ViewModel: NSObject`.

My implementation of `ViewController` is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel: ViewModel

    init(withViewModel viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

`ViewModel` has simple `override init`:

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // Some other logic
    }

}
```

I understand, that I need `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` in `ViewController` implementation since it conforms `NSCoding` protocol. But I'm not sure if it is safe to have `fatalError` there.

When I change `fatalError` to `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` I receive

> property 'self.viewModel' not initialized at super.init call

I don't want to make `viewModel` an optional variable, because in my App logic it can't be `nil`.

Also, when I change `init?(coder...` to

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.viewModel = ViewModel()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

this also doesn't satisfy me, since `viewModel` isn't the only constant, which need to be implemented during initialization of `ViewController`.

So, my questions:

- Is it safe to have `fatalError` in this `init` method?
- I **don't use Storyboards** in my App (only for Launch Screen). Can I be sure, that this `init?(coder...` method won't run in any case?
- Or maybe there is an option to write it without `fatalError`?
- Or do I need a full implementation in it, because in some cases my App will use it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you don't use storyboard you can disable your init, so you won't be able to use it in code:

```
@available(*, unavailable) required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("disabled init")
}
```

Comment: With this line I disable it for all iOS platforms, so I won't be able to init my `ViewController` with `coder`. In fact in my code I never call this init. I want to be sure, that framework won't call it also in any case. So, am I understand correctly, since it is unavailable, and app compile and run, that means that framework also doesn't use it? Sorry for my noob questions, I just want to understand how it works and make it safe :)

Comment: @PeterTretyakov if any framework or any other file will use unavailable `init(coder:)`, you'll see compile error. So if your code is compiles don't worry :)

Comment: If you don't use Storyboards, this signature initializer pops up everywhere. I've started using this oneliner, after Vasilii's example: `@available(*, unavailable) required init?(coder _: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) disabled") }`

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a good startup with dependency injection as well, if you wish to make it easy to write tests for it later with mocked data.

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let viewModel = ViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.runFunction()
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {

    var networkingService: NetworkingService?

    init(withNetworkingService networkingService: NetworkingService = null) {
        self.networkingService = networkingService
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Of course, as you understand, I'm trying to make my code more clear and clean. Dependency Injection is in my learning list, but now I'm trying to understand all under this `init?(coder...` func. So, dependency injection is not the case of this question. But if you provide some links to basic tutorials for DI, I'll appreciate it :)

Comment: If you are in the tutorial stage i would recommend Ray WenderLich, i learnt a lot from him.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/category/swift